# Setup SSL for java API server

Tags: java, ssl

Im running a java-application, Webb-API (REST) and want to make the server be able to handle SSL-requests.
​
How can i set this up?
​
This is my WebConfig.java

```
class WebConfig extends org.gwizard.web.WebConfig {
​
    @Inject
    public.   WebConfig(@Named("server.port") int port) {
        super();
        setPort(port);
​
    }
}
```